# Unknown number of nested list in python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested

How to create a nested list ?
For example there is a list lines[None]*int(nl) where nl is number of lines, input taken from user, and in lines[] I want to create multiple lists which would hold numbers for different lines.

Comment: provide example input and output please

Comment: Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: we are also "code enthusiasts" -- please provide ***some*** code, or *examples* of input & output to clarify what are your "lists" and user input. And you want to create multiple lists...what do you mean "*which would hold numbers for different lines.*"?

Answer (score 0):

the below code shows you how to add a list to a list. i am assuming this is what you wanted

```
list_example = []
# this will be your base list
print (list_example)
#now lets add a sub list
list_example.append([])
print (list_example)
#now lets add a list to that list
list_example[0].append([])
```